# Where should I ask questions about translation from English to Russian?

Tags: перевод

What SE is about translation from English to Russian ?

- Russian.SE ( Seems more for those who learn Russian )
- There are Two English.SE

  - https://ell.stackexchange.com/
  - https://english.stackexchange.com/

Seems this English SEs will ban me automatically.

I don't learn Russian, I learn English. Is this SE for me?

Comment: This question belongs to meta.russian.SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think this question is better suited for meta.russian.SE - I'll flag for moderators to move it there.

As for the actual content of your question, this is indeed the right forum to ask question about translation into Russian, however your questions should not be straight "How do I translate X?" - instead, you need to show some research on your part, e.g. "I believe the right translation is Y, however I'm unsure about the meaning of word Z". Or, "I don't understand the meaning of this phrase; each word means that and that, however put together they make no sense".

The main point is to show that you've done some work rather than expect others to do it for you.  If you ask questions right, people will be more than happy to help you.